# How to fix NaN(Not a number) output in C#/ML.net

Tags: c#, ml.net

The programm succesfully trains(with a dataset of 1600 examples) the model, but when making a prediction it returns NaN(Not a number).
Any help is greatly appreciated, but please keep in mind, that I`m neither an expiereenced programmer nor deep into machine learning.

I already tried to change the values for the prediction to something similar to my dataset;

```
//Column Declaration    
public class WineQualityPrediction
    {
        [ColumnName("Label")]
        public float Label;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pipeline = new LearningPipeline();
            string dataPath = "WineMl.txt";
            pipeline.Add(new TextLoader(dataPath).CreateFrom<WineData>(separator: ','));

            pipeline.Add(new Dictionarizer("Label"));
            pipeline.Add(new ColumnConcatenator("Features", "FixedAcidity", "VolatileAcidity", "CitricAcid", "ResidualSugar", "Chlorides", "FreeSulfurDioxide", "TotalSulfurDioxide", "Density", "pH", "Sulphates", "Alcohol"));

            pipeline.Add(new StochasticDualCoordinateAscentClassifier());
            pipeline.Add(new PredictedLabelColumnOriginalValueConverter() { PredictedLabelColumn = "Label" });

            var model = pipeline.Train<WineData, WineQualityPrediction>();

            var prediction = model.Predict(new WineData { FixedAcidity = 7.4f, VolatileAcidity = 0.7f, CitricAcid = 0.0f, ResidualSugar = 1.9f, Chlorides = 0.076f, FreeSulfurDioxide =11.0f, TotalSulfurDioxide = 34.0f, Density = 0.9978f, pH = 3.51f, Sulphates = 0.56f});

            Console.WriteLine($"Predicted wine quality is: {prediction.Label}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] by providing some data that shows this problem?

Comment: Side note, but I would suggest switching to a more recent version of ML.NET. The version you are using, judging from types like the LearningPipeline are deprecated.